# Backpropagation not working for XOR

Tags: c++, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've been learning about backpropagation the last two weeks, did the math behind it and thought that I understand the topic well enough for my own implementation (without any linear algebra packages etc). Apparently, I was wrong. Below you can find the most simple example network I could think of: 2 hidden units and 1 output unit. I try to learn the XOR function. However, that does not work at all. The prediction is always around `0.5`. I am not sure where I messed up. Maybe someone could help?

```
float sigmoid(float pX) {
    return 1.0f/(1.0f+exp(-1.0f*pX));
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
// DEFINE XOR problem
float examples[4][2] = { {0,0} , {0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1}};
float labels[4] = {0, 1, 1, 0};

/* I want to use a network with two hidden neurons and 1 output neuron 
*/

// Weights from input to hidden neurons
float WInput[2][2];
float WInputBias[2];

// Weights from hidden to output neuron
float WOutput[2];
float WOutputBias;

// output of hidden layer to output neuron
float hidden[2];

// error for hidden layer
float error[2];

//output of network 
float yPred;

// randomly init weights
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::normal_distribution<float> d(0, 0.1);
WInput[0][0] = d(gen); WInput[0][1] = d(gen); 
WInput[1][0] = d(gen); WInput[1][1] = d(gen); 
WInputBias[0] = d(gen); WInputBias[1] = d(gen);
WOutput[0] = d(gen); WOutput[1] = d(gen); WOutputBias = d(gen);

// do the learning
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
        float * input = &examples[k][0];
        float label = labels[k];

        // Compute forward pass
        hidden[0] = sigmoid(WInput[0][0]*input[0] + WInput[1][0]*input[1] + WInputBias[0]);
        hidden[1] = sigmoid(WInput[0][1]*input[0] + WInput[1][1]*input[1] + WInputBias[1]);
        yPred = sigmoid(WOutput[0]*hidden[0] + WOutput[1]*hidden[1] + WOutputBias);

        std :: cout << "Target / Prediction: " << label << " / " << yPred << std :: endl;

        // Backward pass with alpha = 0.1
        float outputError = -(label - yPred)*yPred*(1-yPred);
        WOutput[0] = WOutput[0] - 0.1f*outputError*hidden[0]; //hidden equals input from this layer
        WOutput[1] = WOutput[1] - 0.1f*outputError*hidden[1];
        WOutputBias = WOutputBias - 0.1f*outputError;

        error[0] = (WOutput[0]*outputError)*hidden[0]*(1-hidden[0]);
        error[1] = (WOutput[1]*outputError)*hidden[1]*(1-hidden[1]);

        WInput[0][0] = WInput[0][0] - 0.1f*error[0]*input[0];
        WInput[1][0] = WInput[1][0] - 0.1f*error[0]*input[1];
        WInput[0][1] = WInput[0][1] - 0.1f*error[1]*input[0];
        WInput[1][1] = WInput[1][1] - 0.1f*error[1]*input[1];
        WInputBias[0] = WInputBias[0] - 0.1f*error[0];
        WInputBias[1] = WInputBias[1] - 0.1f*error[1];

    }
    std :: cout << std :: endl;
    // getch();
} 
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that this is too broad. Did you debug it? Can you show a [MCVE]? Here is an awesome and a very straightforward XOR Neural Network Implementation that uses the BackPropagation method, and good luck: https://vimeo.com/19569529

Comment: I know that this is kind of a broad question, but this is the most minimal and complete example I could think of. I'm currently doing some calculus on paper (again), but so far it seems that the forward pass is correctly computed. There must be a problem with the backprop step. Thanks for the video, I already found that one today. I just found the sourcecode in the comments. Maybe that'll help

Comment: In your `//do the learning` loop, you're doing this: `float * input = &examples[k][0]` and trying to use it as an array later on. However, `examples[i][j]` is a float, not a pointer to a float (read: not an array). It seems like in your `//do the learning` loop, you may want this instead: `float * input = &examples[k]`. You are likely getting incorrect inputs that disagree with your expected outputs due to reading past the end of an array (and into the next one, most likely). That is all to say, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Your suggestion wont work, because I need a pointer fo float, not a pointer to float[2].In the words of gcc: `error: cannot convert ‘float (*)[2]’ to ‘float*’ in initialization`. To get a `float *`, I use the first entry of the input and get its address. This is pretty much the same as `&(*examples[k])`. However, I double checked the input. Its always (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) or (1,1) as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken another look and the code, and played around with some parameters, and it turns out that all of the code is actually correct.

The problem is, with only 2 hidden nodes, this problem is rather difficult to learn, and the number of epochs you used (1000) combined with the learning rate you used (0.1) simply means it doesn't converge yet.

Try letting it train for about 4000-6000 epochs (or, preferably, until the absolute values of your errors drop below some threshold), and try mutliplying the weight updates by 1.0 instead of 0.1. Then you should get better results.

It may also help to randomly initialize the weights to lie in [-0.1, 0.1] instead of [0.0, 0.1]. This shouldn't make a huge difference though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is the error (delta) of the output layer. From my point of view this is correct (although I see your problem), its the derivative of the error function (I used RMSE) multiplied by the derivative of the activation function (sigmoid here). Just look at e.g. [link](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html) eq 30 / bp 1 or look at the corresponding wikipedia article [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems you are correct. With increased learning rate, I need about 1000 epochs for 100% accuracy. One side note: I use `std::normal_distribution<float> d(0, 0.1);` for weight initialization, meaning I already have positive and negative weights.